# Hidden “if” and converting to a question

Tags: sentence-structure, question

I have this sentence:

> Wollen wir Schritt halten, müssen wir laufend dazulernen.

Is it correct to just add a question mark to convert it to a question?

> Wollen wir Schritt halten, müssen wir laufend dazulernen?

Or do I need to add a *dann*?

> Wollen wir Schritt halten, müssen wir dann laufend dazulernen?

Comment: Side remark about style: _Schritt halten_ and _laufend_ both are figurative and originally refer to people walking. When they are used independently, they don’t mix well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither version works particularly well as a question because the hint that it is meant as a question comes too late and is inconspicuous, even with *dann* (because this word also has other meanings). It is a bit clearer when an explicit *wenn* is used, emphasizing the correspondence *wenn – dann*:

> Wenn wir Schritt halten wollen, müssen wir dann laufend dazulernen?

The most natural way, however, is to have the main clause first:

> Müssen wir laufend dazulernen, wenn wir Schritt halten wollen?